# Ant: How to use a property value as replacement in replaceregexp

Tags: regex, ant, properties

I need to replace a regex match with a value from a properties file.

It would look like:

```
<replaceregexp 
        file="test.txt"
        match="blabla" 
        replace="some.property"
        >
</replaceregexp>
```

(That doesn't work, it's just to show what I need)

some.property is in a file called test.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are using some.property instead of ${some.property}. That's how I have it working.

Comment: Wow, somehow I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar requirement, I need match a value from a property file and change it to another value if it exists. I need to set the property if it does not exist.

Comment: well ant does those things for you automatically i.e if you define a property prop1 in a property file that will be the value as default, you could change that value by calling ant and passing -Dprop1=newValue as a parameter, but I whould suggest you to create a new question so I could write longer answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [loadproperties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) task to load properties from a file.